# How can I get a coordinate grid for certain coordinates on the X,Y and Z axis?

Tags: python

```
coordinates = []
repeats = 2  
grid_size = 4     
for c in itertools.product(range(grid_size), range(grid_size), range(grid_size)):
    for _ in range(repeats):
        coordinates.append(list(c))
```

until now I used this code because I had the same points on all the axis (0,1,2,3)

Now it has changed and I have
0,1,2,3 on the X axis
0,1,2,3,4,5,6 on the Y axis
0.1,0.6,1.3 on the Z axis

I want to repeat every coordinate 2 times by row, thats why I have repeats in the code

Thanks in advance!

The code I tried before:

```
coordinates = []
repeats = 2  
grid_size = 4     
for c in itertools.product(range(grid_size), range(grid_size), range(grid_size)):
    for _ in range(repeats):
        coordinates.append(list(c))
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `itertools.product(range(4), range(7), [0.1, 0.6, 1.3])`